# Raspbian Jessie Lite "Factory Reset"

Tags: linux, ssh, raspbian

I am currently remoting offsite to my Raspberry and since I think I messed up all packages and configuration files I would like to return to default settings before installing all the packages and start over, kind of "factory reset".

I am using Raspbian Jessie Lite.

Anyone know a way to do this remotely using ssh?